# Is there a way to print help for one command of CMake without typing out the entire command?

Tags: linux, cmake

Say, I want to print help for `set_tests_properties`, then I need this command line.

```
cmake --help-command set_tests_properties
```

I need to type **every** characters of `--help-command`, because command line auto-completion isn't working when I type `tab` key, which is painful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write an auto-completion script?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'll look into it, never knew that I can write a script to achieve it, Thanks!

Comment: or better [use others code and don't reinvent the wheel](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+auto-completion)

Comment: you could also set an alias. Like `alias cmakeh='cmake --help-command'`

Comment: @PSandro Very simple and works fine! I'll stick to this method.